# $h_*:S_*(X\times Y)\to S_*(X\times Y)$ a homomorphism of natural chain complexes. If $h_0=Id$, show that $h_*$ is homotopic to $Id$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

**Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $h_*:S_*(X\times Y)\to S_*(X\times Y)$ a homomorphism of natural chain complexes. If $h_0=Id$, show that $h_*$ is homotopic to $Id$.**

To solve this problem I have thought about using naturalness. So first I proof this result for $ X=\Delta_n$ and $Y=\Delta_n$, where $h_*':S_*(\Delta_n\times \Delta_n)\to S_*(\Delta_n\times \Delta_n)$ is homotopic to $Id$. I also have the following diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
S_*(\Delta_n\times \Delta_n) @> h_*' >> S_*(\Delta_n\times \Delta_n)  \\
 @V f_1 VV @V f_0 VV    @. \\
S_*(X\times Y) @> h_* >> S_*(X\times Y) 
\end{CD}
$$

But I don't know what functions to put on the vertical lines. It follows that $h_*$ is homotopic to $Id$? Why? Thank you.

Comment: acyclic models?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown
I don't know what acyclic models are, sorry.

Comment: I guess $h_*$ induced by a map $h : X \times Y \to  X \times Y$. What is $h_0$?